# LARGE Conditional Function

Tags: excel, function

To find the nth largest value in a dataset, I use the LARGE function:

```
=LARGE(B2:K11,1)
=LARGE(B2:K11,2)
=LARGE(B2:K11,3)
```

Each of the rows 2-11 are names with a colour. I would like to find the nth largest value in a single row of this dataset (B2:K11), although the row is subject to change based on a different cell. So if cell A1 contains orange, and the data for orange is in row 6, then the function will return the nth largest value in B6:K6. If cell A1 contains blue, and the data for blue is in row 3, then the function will return the nth largest value in B3:K3.

I am not sure how to incorporate this into the LARGE function, or if a different function would be better suited to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following function

```
=LARGE(OFFSET(A2,MATCH(A1,A2:A11,0)-1,1,1,10),2)
```

Will do what you want... (assuming that your colours are in column A and the horizontal range spans 10 columns).

If you need the function to refer to different sheets then you just need to prefix the ranges with the sheet name..

```
=LARGE(OFFSET(Sheet2!A2,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A2:A11,0)-1,1,1,10),2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam, but a couple of follow-up questions: (1) I want to reference a cell rather than a word "Orange", given that the cell contents will change, and (2) The reference cell may also be on a different worksheet - will the OFFSET function work if the reference cell and table are on different worksheets?

Comment: @user2696883 I edited my answer..... Yes, the offset function should work fine in your situation.